# How can I add a char on the begining of a string in C?

Tags: c, char, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

I'm trying to put a char on the begining of a string but when I print the final string the result is:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

This is my code:

```
char * letter=malloc(strlen(output)+2);
letter[0]='a';
strcat(letter,output);
output=malloc(strlen(output)+2);
strcpy(output,letter);
free(letter);
printf("\n%s",output);
```

`output` is string input that i give to the method.

Comment: `letter` needs to be null-terminated in order for you to use `strcat(letter, output)` correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `strcat` the destination array shall contain a string. Your array `letter` does not contain a string.

You could write for example

```
letter[0] = 'a';
letter[1] = '\0';
strcat( letter, output );
```

or just

```
letter[0] = 'a';
strcpy( letter + 1, output );
```

Pay attention to that it seems this statement

```
output=malloc(strlen(output)+2);
```

produces a memory leak because the previously allocated memory pointed to by the pointer `output` was not freed.

The task could be done without allocating a memory for an auxiliary array. You could use the standard function `realloc` to reallocate the original array pointed to by `output`. And then move the stored string using `memmove` to the right one position and then insert the character `'a'` in the first position.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 5;
    char *s = malloc( n * sizeof( char ) );
    strcpy( s, "ello" );
    
    char *tmp = realloc( s, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );
    
    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        s = tmp;
        memmove( s + 1, s, n );
        s[0] = 'H';
        ++n;
    }
    
    puts( s );
    
    free( s );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
```